# Could not find stored procedure on update

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

what i want to do is while user click the link, the clicks will increase by 1 but i failed to to do=(

**output**

Could not find stored procedure 'updateMovieClicks'How to win in share?','64'

**my stored procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE updateMovieClicks
(
@movieTitle varchar(50),
@movieClicks int
)
AS
update MovieListTable set movieClicks=@movieClicks where movieTitle=@movieTitle;
```

**my programs code on page load**

```
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmdIncreaseMovieClicks = new SqlCommand("updateMovieClicks'" +
    Session["videoName"].ToString() + "','" + clicksIncrease + "'", conn);
SqlParameter movieTitle = new SqlParameter();
SqlParameter movieClicks = new SqlParameter();
cmdIncreaseMovieClicks.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdIncreaseMovieClicks.Parameters.Add("@movieClick", SqlDbType.Int).Value 
= clicksIncrease+1;
cmdIncreaseMovieClicks.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: You haven't set the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is ocurring because the system thinks you are trying to find a stored procedure called `'updateMovieClicks'How to win in share?','64'`. This is because you have concatenated your parameters in a string with your stored procedure name.

---

When specifying that a command is of type `StoredProcedure` then you add your parameters seperately to the command text. Therefore only the stored procedure name goes in the command text, and the parameters are added as seperate objects to the SqlCommand.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE updateMovieClicks
(
@movieTitle varchar(50)
)
AS
update MovieListTable set movieClicks=(movieClicks+1) where movieTitle=@movieTitle;


SqlCommand cmdIncreaseMovieClicks = new SqlCommand("updateMovieClicks", conn);
cmdIncreaseMovieClicks.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdIncreaseMovieClicks.Parameters.Add("@movieTitle", SqlDbType.nvarchar).Value 
= session["videoName"].tostring();
conn.Open();
cmdIncreaseMovieClicks.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Here I've also improved your Stored Procedure query so that the `movieClicks` is calculated at SQL level.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to specify the stored proc name in your SqlCommand's constructor.

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("updateMovieClicks",conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movieTitle", Session["videoName"].ToString() );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movieClicks", int.Parse(clicksIncrease));
```